# Invoking a Command from Database String

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am working in a cluster Quartz/Spring Batch environment and I need to invoke a number of shell scripts at various time of the day. The administrator do not want us to maintain the scripts on all the Spring Batch machines and they do not want o use a shared filing system.

I was thinking about storing the shell scripts in the database, but I have not been able to figure out how to replace `ProcessBuilder(commandFile)` the commandFile with a byte stream.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you store shell script in the database ?

Comment: The are multiple options here. Two options are to store it as a file on the database or as a byte array in a CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be a `byteStream`? `ProcessBuilder` appears to take either  list of `String`s or a vararg of `String`s - can't you read from the commands from the database as String?

Comment: Sorry I meant Byte Array not byte stream. The string it takes is a name of the file with it arguments.